# File not found with Java's getResource

Tags: java, file

I am trying to load a file called `Test` from my class, but somehow Java says, that the file does not exist, while it clearly does and neither the URL object `url` is null nor does it contain an invalid path and when I debug the program, the File object `file` has the right path stored in it. When I print out `file.getPath()` and paste it into the Windows Explorer it opens up just fine. I am running Eclipse, but I tried running the program in a console and it doesn't work either.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    URL url = Test.class.getResource("/Test");
    File file = new File(url.toExternalForm());

    if (!file .exists()) {
      System.out.println("File does not exist: " + file.getPath());
      System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

I tried it with `getResource("Test")`, `File("Test")` and `File("/Test")` as well, but that didn't work either. I don't know why this happens know, since I work often with files and never had a problem.

The file I want to load is located in a source folder and yes, I checked, it is recognized as a source folder in Eclipse and is in the classpath. By the way the file *is* actually just called `Test` without an extension.

Bin folder:

```
bin/
  |___package/Test.class
  |___Test
```

Output (Project is called "Other"):

```
File does not exist: file:\F:\Development\CoolDirectory\Other\bin\Test
```

Comment: FilePath should not have "file:\" prefix.

Comment: Thanks @shan I found a fix thanks to you. I falsely used `url.toExternalForm()` instead of `url.getFile()`

Comment: Please tell us what you really want to do. Accessing a resource via `getResource(..)` is one way, but a very complicated and error prone. If you want read the file `getResourceAsStream(..)` is the better alternative.

Comment: Your assuming that the URL returned by `getResource` is a `file:`; that sounds like a bad idea. If the resource doesn't exist, `getResource` will return null. Couldn't you use `url.openStream()` to read the file?

Comment: There's no file extension for the string of "/Test" you provided. What type of file is this? It would make more sense to have something like "Test.txt" or "Test.pdf" as your argument. Also, it should be `!file.exists()` instead of `!file. exists()` - there shouldn't be a space.

Comment: @Robert I just need to populate a String with the content of my file, so essentially I need `new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()))`

Comment: @MaxVoisard it is in fact `!file.exists()` in my code I just made a typo when pasting the code in here and the type of file I am working with shouldn't and doesn't have an extension.

Comment: @Sheldon: As I wrote: If you want to read the file content never use `getResource(..)` (unless are sadomasochistic and prefers to hard way with lot's of bugs and errors).

Comment: Resources are not files. To read a resource use `URL#openStream()` to get an `InputStream` or get the `InputStream` directly via `#getResourceAsStream(String)`. Then read the bytes from it. If using Java 9+ you can use [`InputStream#readAllBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html). Note you can also create a `Reader` from the `InputStream`.

Comment: @Sheldon You just helped me out on my homework 3 years later, thanks. I was trying to access a file using "urL" when I needed "url.getFile()" haha

Answer (score 3):

Using `Test.class.getResource("/Test");` can cause a lot of trouble as you never know if the resource is a plain file or inside a JAR file are somehow not directly accessible.

Therefore the preferred way is to use `getResourceAsStream(String)` which returns an InputStream you can directly read from.

The following example used Java 9+ featured:

```
    byte[] data = null;
    try (InputStream in = Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/Test")) {
        if (in == null) {
            System.out.println("Resource '/Test' does not exist");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        data = in.readAllBytes();
    }
```

Comment: Why would `getResource()` cause troubles in a JAR? I thought the only difference between those two was that `getResource` returns an `URL`, while `getResourceAsStream` returns an `InputStream` and is a shorthand for `getResource`

Comment: @Sheldon A file inside a Jar file can't be accessed directly using `File` class. Therefore for every case you have to implement specific ways. `getResourceAsStream()` does everything for you.